# Copy project / View dashboard for arbitrary snapshot?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

We use SonarQube (5.1) to scan our sources currently being developed (ie. SVN/trunk resp. GIT/develop or master branch) on a nightly basis with Jenkins + sonar-runner. In addition, after creating the release branch, we scan the release sources for each release build. Now we need a report (which would be basically a PDF or so of a SonarQube dashboard) for each release build for ISO27001 reasons containing for example the number of issues and OWASP violations in each category.

In order to achieve this goal, the following options have been evaluated:

1. Use two SonarQube projects per deployable, one for trunk, one for the releases and create a PDF version of the release project dashboard after SonarQube scan. **Issues:** No way to copy project settings, false-positives etc. automatically, i.e. both projects need to be synchronized manually, which is not really feasible.
2. Use a single SonarQube project for trunk and release builds and create report immediately after SonarQube scan. **Issues:** No access to historical dashboard data, i.e. if a trunk build runs immediately after a release build, the release build results are gone. The asynchronous processing of the scan-results introduced in SonarQube 5 makes it even more complicated to automate.

So what I could imagine would help us to achieve our goal is either

- a way to initialize a new SonarQube project (release) based on an old (trunk) one (with settings, false-positives etc. copied, w/o history) to basically automatically create a new SonarQube project for each release version based on the SonarQube trunk project at this point in time -or-
- a way to view an arbitrary dashboard for an arbitrary older scan

Or is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Reports plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/report/) (Commercial). It lets you email a specific dashboard (default or custom) as a PDF. The only hitch would be the scheduling. You could generate them on demand, but as you say, back-to-back builds would leave a very small report generation window.

On the other hand, it sounds like your "release build" is a separate job? If that's the case, you could add report generation as a build step to the release build job to have it run automatically as part of the release. Make the release build job and the normal build job mutually exclusive and your "tiny report window" problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Using a single project is IMHO still some kind of workaround and spoils the project history in SonarQube. Is there no other way to handle trunk and release builds of a project separately while using the same/copied project configuration in SonarQube?

Comment: SonarQube doesn't yet handle branches well in terms of FP's & etc.